# JS GST calculation form total is multiplying more then it should

Tags: javascript, html

My total is * 10 for some reason, i have made some stupid mistake somewhere. Just working out a calculation method for the form i am building but stuck on the last element.

The gst input has no decimal place which i am not overly bothered with it at this point it can be added later but from what i see it should just + both elements and output.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updatePrice() {
      // Get the ex-GST price from its form element
var exPrice = document.getElementById("ex-gst").value;
var TPrice = document.getElementById("gst").value;

// Get the GST price
gstPrice = exPrice * 0.1;
TPrice = gstPrice + exPrice;

// Set the GST price in its form element
document.getElementById("gst").value = gstPrice;
document.getElementById("inc-gst").value = TPrice;

}
</script>

<table border=0 cellspacing=2 cellpadding=2>
      <tr>
        <th width="5"> </th>
        <th width="264"> </th>
        <th><font size="2" face="Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Attendees</font></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align=center> </td>
        <td align=right>Calculate</td>
        <td align=right> <input id="ex-gst" name="ex-gst" value="0.00" size=7 maxlength=10 onChange="updatePrice()"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align=center> </td>
        <td align=right> 12.5% G.S.T </td>
        <td align=right> <input type=text id="gst" name="gst" size=7 maxlength=10 value="0.00" onChange="updatePrice()"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align=center> </td>
        <td align=right>Total Payable</td>
        <td align=right> $
            <input name="inc-gst" id="inc-gst" type="text" value="0.00" size=7 maxlength=10  onChange="updatePrice(this.form)">
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `gstPrice = exPrice * 0.1;` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

got it working, just had to make some slight edits

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updatePrice() {
      // Get the ex-GST price from its form element
var exPrice = document.getElementById("ex-gst").value;
var gstPrice = document.getElementById("gst").value;

// Get the GST price
gstPrice = exPrice * 0.1;
var TPrice = parseInt(gstPrice) + parseInt(exPrice);

// Set the GST price in its form element
document.getElementById("gst").value = gstPrice;
document.getElementById("inc-gst").value = TPrice;

}
</script>

<table border=0 cellspacing=2 cellpadding=2>
      <tr>
        <th width="5"> </th>
        <th width="264"> </th>
        <th><font size="2" face="Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Attendees</font></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align=center> </td>
        <td align=right>Calculate</td>
        <td align=right> <input id="ex-gst" name="ex-gst" value="0.00" size=7 maxlength=10 onChange="updatePrice()"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align=center> </td>
        <td align=right> 12.5% G.S.T </td>
        <td align=right> <input type=text id="gst" name="gst" size=7 maxlength=10 value="0.00" onChange="updatePrice()"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align=center> </td>
        <td align=right>Total Payable</td>
        <td align=right> $
            <input name="inc-gst" id="inc-gst" type="text" value="0.00" size=7 maxlength=10  onChange="updatePrice(this.form)">
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be `parseFloat()` - else the decimal points will be ignored/converted to integer. `gstPrice = parseFloat(exPrice) * 0.1;
TPrice = parseFloat(gstPrice) + parseFloat(exPrice);`